# can't populate simple collection and output to view

Tags: backbone.js

As you can see, I am very new at backbone, and I can't work out why this is not working???

I am getting this error?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

### CODE

```
TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({});

TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TodoItem,
    url: "todo"
});

var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#content',
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function(model) {
        this.$el.html('test');
    }
});

$(function() {

    var todoList = new TodoList();

    todoList.fetch();

    new TodoView();

});
```

### URL TODO - JSON

> [   {description: 'Pick up milk.', status: 'incomplete', id: 1},
>   {description: 'Get a car wash', status: 'incomplete', id: 2} ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `this.model` in your view:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
},
```

but you don't specify a model when you create the view:

```
new TodoView();
```

That should look more like:

```
new TodoView({ model: some_model })
```

If you want the `TodoView` to look at the whole collection then use `this.collection`:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);
}
```

and supply the `collection` option when creating the view:

```
new TodoView({ collection: todoList });
```

Also note that `todoList.fetch();` is an AJAX call so you probably won't have anything in `todoList` when you create your view, you can bind to the `'reset'` event to re-render when something shows up:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.collection.on('change', this.render);
    this.collection.on('reset',  this.render);
}
```

You can also use [`_.bindAll`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll) to bind a function to `this`, that way you don't need to use the third parameter to `on`.

BTW, `bind` is an alias for `on`, `bind` still works but `on` is the preferred method for new code; AFAIK, the name was changed to `on` to better match the newer jQuery naming scheme.

Comment: thanks that has resolved the error.  Now i can't seem to get the view to render anything.  Im trying something static first then will try getting the json to display.  Any help would be great.

Comment: @johnstontrav: Do you have anything with `id="content"` in the DOM?

Comment: thanks mu,  I have worked it out i think.  my json needed " around the keys.